# Aurelia: Using KendoUI Core

Tags: kendo-ui, aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I downloaded kendoui core from Telerik's website. Folder has a js directory with separate files for each widget. I want to integrate kendoui with systemJS in my Aurelia app(built on top of skeleton-navigation). I was able to do this with JQueryUI as follows:

--Created a "jquery-ui@1.11.4" folder containing the jqueryUI JavaScript lib in github folder in jspm_packages folder

--Created a file called "jquery-ui@1.11.4.js" that exports the lib above like so:

module.exports = require("github:github/jquery-ui@1.11.4/jquery-ui.js")

--Defined jqueryui in my config file: "jquery-ui": "github:github/jquery-ui@1.11.4"

Now, if I want to use any widget, like the datepicker, i do this:

import { datepicker } from 'jquery-ui';

How do I do this for kendoUI? I read somewhere that the "kendo.core.js" file contains all widgets but it seems too lightweight and using it alone didnt work. It also has a complementary .map file. What is it for?

UPDATE: As suggested in the answer below, I decided to include kendoUI and jQuery with the script tag in my index page. Also instead of importing the whole kendoUI library (kendo.ui.core.min.js->670KB) I just included the files needed for kendoUI's date picker that I needed (kendo.core, kendo.popup, kendo.calendar and kendo.datepicker->99.1KB). Incase anyone wants to use this approach, Remember that jQuery will have to be imported in index.html too and before any kendo files. Also, kendo.core should be imported before the others and datepicker after everything else(I.e. last)

Comment: https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-kendoui-bridge you may want to consider this, the community has done a lot of work integrating aurelia with kendo and we've managed to get cool stuff working like aurelia bindings, custom elements for each control, aurelia templates in kendo widgets etc etc. Check out the demos.

Comment: I've written a blog that might interest you about integrating third party libraries into Aurelia here: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you are using for adding jQuery UI is not one that will scale. You should never write anything to the `jspm_packages` folder, as that folder is jspm's to use as it wishes. Also, you can simply install jQueryUI using JSPM (`jspm install jquery-ui`).

Your first option is to install KendoUI Core using jspm with `jspm install kendo-ui`.

If you'd prefer to go it alone, you should probably just load the kendo files using a `<script>` element. There's nothing wrong with doing this. These files are made to be used as global variables loaded using script tags, so don't fight it.

Again, there's nothing wrong with using script elements to load legacy (read non-modular) js files.

Comment: I checked that before. Not what I'm looking for . I want to write my own implementation. It's not a question of making custom elements bit importing the kendoui files properly with systemJS

Comment: In that case, this more of a jspm/systemjs question than an Aurelia or KendoUI question. I'd recommend adding those tags.

Comment: I've edited the answer, hopefully it's more useful now.

Comment: I have an issue with installing things with jspm(bad network). That's why I'm adding jQueryUI(and jQuery itself) manually. I will try using the script tag. And with reference to you referring to kendoui as legacy js files, if kendoui can be installed with jspm doesn't it make it modular?

Comment: SystemJS can load global files. It does look like the version of kendo that jspm installs is in AMD format though: https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/master/package-overrides/github/kendo-labs/bower-kendo-ui%402015.1.511.json

Comment: Also, to note, on the core team we use script tags to load stuff from time to time when building our own Aurelia applications.

Comment: As I mentioned before I was trying to import "kendo.core.min.js". Apparently that was just a wrapper or something. The real file with all the widgets is "kendo.ui.core.min.js". Importing the script didn't work because jQuery must be defined first. I import jQuery with systemJS later in a virwModel. No I need to import jQuery as a script too in index.html. I think I will take your advice and check aurelia-kendo-ui-bridge